# SQL inject - BadStore.net

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

I'm studying some topics of software security and I found this site : 
http://teachcryptography.blogspot.com.br/2015/03/badstore-funway-of-exploiting-web.html

I'm trying to leak data using SQL inject in Quick Item Search form.
Here is the query :

```
"SELECT itemnum, sdesc, ldesc, price FROM itemdb WHERE '$squery' IN
(itemnum,sdesc,ldesc)";
```

I got the right answer with this input : `1=1'/*` but the input `'-'` is also right. Could someone explain to me why?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the single hyphen/minus `-` is right? What types of values are in the columns `itemnum, sdesc,ldesc`?

Comment: Commonly, SQL injection probes will use 2 hyphens followed by a space, which is a SQL inline comment `' -- ` to comment out the remaining part of the statement.  Please clarify for us exactly what the correct value is. Format it as inline code by surrounding in backticks `\`1=1...\`` so all the chars are preserved.

Comment: With this two inputs => 1=1'/* , '-' . I got to see all products. I don't know why this '-' work.
@MichaelBerkowski the types are int, varchar , varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `'-'` (single-quote, hyphen, single-quote) works because of the integer to string casting behavior of some RDBMS. Since what you posted looks like PHP code, I will make the assumption that the database involved is MySQL.

In MySQL, a non-numeric string cast to an integer will result in zero.  Further, attempting an arithmetic operation on two strings will first cause them to be cast to integers.  So let's look at the string after the value is substituted:

```
WHERE ''-'' IN (itemnum, sdesc,ldesc)
```

MySQL will attempt to do *subtraction* of the two empty strings `''`, so literally: `'' minus ''`.  To accomplish that, they must first be cast to integers, which are zero (`0-0=0`).  Now it looks like:

```
WHERE 0 IN (itemnum, sdesc,ldesc)
```

For the same reason that the non-numeric string casts to zero, this time MySQL will cast the `varchar` columns `sdesc, ldesc` to an integer. Unless they begin with numbers, the result of that cast is zero.  The `0` from `''-''` then works because the `IN()` will match any of the listed columns and the `varchar` have all been cast to equivalent `0`.

Here's MySQL attempting arithmetic on the strings:

```
> select ''-'';
+-------+
| ''-'' |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

Here's MySQL casting the empty string to 0:

```
 > select CAST('' AS SIGNED);
+--------------------+
| CAST('' AS SIGNED) |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
```

Finally, here's MySQL returning `TRUE` because integer `0` matches string values:

```
> SELECT 0 IN (123, 'abc', 'def');
+--------------------------+
| 0 IN (123, 'abc', 'def') |
+--------------------------+
|                        1 |
+--------------------------+
```