# Badstore SQL injection : text does not work

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, security

Let me first accept that I have gone through this
[SQL Injection on BadStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880418/sql-injection-on-badstore)
and, this
[SQL inject - BadStore.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928086/sql-inject-badstore-net)

where the question on similar topic were asked but I am here with a different query.

While learning SQL injection on BadStore, I tried following two arguements:
`abc' or '1'='1`
and
`123' or '1'='1`
the former query with "abc" did not work while the latter one with "123" worked. I believe that sql injection depends on `'1'='1` part and the things preceeding it has no value. But here I am seeing something else.

the query is
`SELECT itemnum, sdesc, ldesc, price FROM itemdb WHERE 'abc' or '1'='1' IN (itemnum,sdesc,ldesc)`

Please explain why the `abc` did not work and `123` worked. I am clueless here.

Comment: Study [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) and [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) then evaluate both expressions step-by-step manually...

Comment: Hi @Akina , I tried to read the topics that you suggested me. What I understood, Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong, from it is that first, 1 despite being inside quotes will be calculated as an integer. Second, because of operator precedence = is calculated first which gives true then OR is calculated. 
What I still failed to understand is that if '1'='1' is being calculated first and is true then why `'abc'` is being treated differently than `'123'` while according to me, it shouldn't even matter. Should it.?

Comment: `=` as comparing operator has the higher priority so this comparing is evaluated firstly. Both its operands are `'1'` and hence have string type, so they are compared as strings. The comparing result is TRUE which is an alias of numeric `1`. PS. If the expression would be `1 = '1'` then the operation have numeric context, and `'1'` would be converted to `1`.

Comment: Then `OR` operator is evaluated. Its operands are `'abc'` and TRUE (obtained previously). The context of `OR` operator is integer-numeric only, so both operands will be converted to numeric datatype unconditionally. TRUE is an alias of 1 and does not need in convertion. `'abc'` is string literal and must be converted, but it starts from a letter hence the convertion will fail.

Comment: @Akina As per my understanding, after going through your suggestion is that the code is running in the following manner. 
fir the expression `'1' ='1' IN (itemno, idsec.....)` is being evaluated. which is giving a false. after that `'abc' OR False` is evaluated where `'abc'` being non-numeric returns false, while for `'123'` being numeric it returns true thus the `OR` Condition is satisfied.

Comment: @Akina
I reached to this conclusion after editing my query in the following manner 
`SELECT itemnum, sdesc, ldesc, price FROM itemdb WHERE  '1'='1' OR 'abc' IN (itemnum,sdesc,ldesc)` and this worked. Please see that I have switched the places for `'abc'` and `'1' = '1'`